# Cannot access array of buttons within the same class

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, I have an ASPX file with 9 buttons (Working on a TicTacToe game so each button has the same OnClick method) and on C#, I find and store all these buttons in an array like so:

```cs
public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected static Button[] buttons;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            initialConditions();
        }
    }

    private void initialConditions() {
        buttons = findButtons();

        // Can access and modify buttons here
        foreach (var btn in buttons) {
            btn.Text = "this does work";
        }

        // Cant modify buttons here
        accessButtons();
    }

    private Button[] findButtons() {
        List<Button> tmpButtons = new List<Button>();
        foreach (var item in board.Controls) {
            if (item is Button) {
                tmpButtons.Add((Button)item);
            }
        }
        return tmpButtons.ToArray();
    }

    private void accessButtons() {
        foreach (var button in buttons) {
            button.Text = "this wont work";
        }
    }
}
```

I can modify buttons after initialising the array in `initialCondition()` method but `accessButtons()` method cannot access those very same buttons. I guess it has something to do with reference and instance stuff but I cannot get my head around this. How can I access and modify this array of buttons anywhere within the class easily with for loops and such?

Edit: I tried initialising the array like `protected static Button[] buttons = findButtons();` but when I do so, I have to make `accessbuttons()` a static method but then it cannot access `board` element on ASPX so I could not figure that one out.

Comment: The code you've produced does not give any compile errors. What do you mean by *"`accessButtons()` method cannot access those very same buttons"*?

Comment: Is it intentional that `buttons` is `static`? Do you want multiple instances of the class to manipulate the same collection?

Comment: Don't make the array static! If you do, it's shared between every instance of the page for that process.

Comment: @RufusL Yes, it does not produce any compilation errors but it simply does not work. `accessButtons` should be changing every buttons text to "this wont work" but it does not. And no, `buttons` should not have been `static`. It seems I forgot to revert it back after one of my trials

Comment: Removing `static` may be enough to resolve the issue, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you change this:

```
   private void accessButtons() {
        foreach (var button in buttons) {
            button.Text = "this wont work";
        }
    }
```

To this:

```
   private void accessButtons() {
        foreach (var button in findButtons()) {
            button.Text = "this wont work";
        }
    }
```

Because this;

```
protected static Button[] buttons;
```

is `protected static`

So you can only access it like so;

```
var buttons = Index.buttons;
```

but it will be null or empty since its not filled anywhere.

Comment: This is not an issue of access. `protected` means that only memebers of the class or other classes that inherit this class can access the field. `static` means that there's only one instance of the object that's accessible to all instances of the class. Both `findButtons` and `accessButtons` have the same access level, therefore the code to iterate the buttons will work the same in both of them.

Comment: Wow, this solution is genius. I think I now see what it is doing and what I was doing wrong. It does access those buttons directly instead of their references, right?

Comment: Adding the `Index` prefix from inside the class is optional (and flagged as "redundant" by resharper). Also, this code is modifying a temporary list of buttons returned from the `findButtons()` method, not the `static Button[] buttons` field.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
protected static Button[] buttons;
```

To this:

```
protected List<Button> buttons;
```

And this:

```
private Button[] findButtons() {
    List<Button> tmpButtons = new List<Button>();
    foreach (var item in board.Controls) {
        if (item is Button) {
            tmpButtons.Add((Button)item);
        }
    }
    return tmpButtons.ToArray();
}
```

To this:

```
private List<Button> findButtons() {
    return board.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
}
```

And finally this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        initialConditions();
    }
}
```

To this:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    initialConditions();
}
```

Notice that every one of these changes results in *less code* than you had before.

For this last change, remember that every server event (including button clicks) is a complete round-trip between the web server and the browser, with a completely different instance of the page class. You have to rebuild that array on **every** run through the page life cycle, and if you want ViewState to work you need to do it *before* `Page_Load()`.

Comment: It is a lot cleaner than my code and I did not know `Page_PreInit` so thank you :) I know have another tool in my arsenal. However, these do not solve the problem of accessing `buttons` from another method themselves. The solution was to use `foreach (var button in findButtons())` instead of `foreach(var button in buttons)` so it can access the very same buttons instead of their references.

Comment: @ÖzençB. These changes should let you use the `buttons` member in any other method (this is another reason we removed the `if(!IsPostBack)` check). Calling `findButtons()` every time does the extra work of searching and building the collection every time.

Comment: I applied your recommendations but `accessButtons()` still cannot access buttons. I get an `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` error.

Comment: `accessbutton()` can't run until after `initialConditions()`

Comment: Oh, and `initialConditions()` needs to keep the `buttons = findButtons();` code. You have to do this exactly **once** at the beginning of the page life cycle.